# Retrigger the azure devops failed gates

Tags: azure-devops

we are using azure devops gates in release pipeline where we check whether we have rolled out  some x percentage in that stage and then kick off the next deployment stage . issue we are facing is sometime we see issue with kusto cluster and then our gates also fail but in reality deployment was rolled out , now if any one sees in azure devops release UI , it will show as "Failed" and we have no option to retrigger post deployment gate and kick off the next stage manually .

we should have option to retrigger the post deployment gates , so that it will show that as Pass

Answer (score 0):

From the requirement, you need to retrigger the post deployment gates after the gates are failed.

I'm afraid there is no such option to only retrigger post deployment gates.

For a workaround, you need to redeploy the target stage and the post deployment gates will be triggered again.

[image]

On the other hand, I can fully understand your requirement. You can create a [Suggestion Ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report the feature requirement.